# Converting US date to EU date in java

Tags: java, string, date

Without using a "dateformat" or something along those lines, I am trying to change a string of US date "mm/dd/yyyy" to an EU format "dd/mm/yyyy". I am to do this using strings and string methods. I feel like I am very close to this but cannot quite figure it out.
This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DateChange {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        String usDate, euDate, day, month;
        int year;
        System.out.println("Enter a date in the form month/day/year:");
        usDate = kbd.nextLine();
        month = usDate.substring(0, '/');
        day = usDate.substring('/', '/');
        year = usDate.lastIndexOf('/');
        euDate = day + "." + month + "." + year;
        System.out.println("Your date in European form is:");
        System.out.println(euDate);
    }

}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 47
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
    at DateChange.main(DateChange.java:12)
```

Comment: Hint: `System.out.println((int) '/');` prints 47.

Comment: would you mind elaborating on that a little more?

Comment: You are giving `substring` the `/` character which means "integer 47". It is not the _index_ of said character.

Comment: There's a [framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) for that.

Comment: oh ok, so i will need to change the substring to indexOf?

Comment: @T3rm3nator not necessary, you just need to figure out the correct offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [java.String.substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) takes two **int** values, not **char** values. The int value of ' / ' is 47, so substring is taking 47 as an input, not the **indexOf**   ' / '.

If you want to solve this without using the java library, use the following code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class DateChange {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        String usDate, euDate, day = "", month = "", year = "";
        System.out.println("Enter a date in the form month/day/year:");
        usDate = kbd.nextLine();
        kbd.close();
        month = usDate.substring(0, usDate.indexOf("/"));
        day = usDate.substring(usDate.indexOf("/")+1, usDate.lastIndexOf("/"));
        year = usDate.substring(usDate.lastIndexOf("/")+1, usDate.length());
        euDate = day + "." + month + "." + year;
        System.out.println("Your date in European form is:");
        System.out.println(euDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: ah I see. I had changed the strings day, month, year to ints, and it runs the whole program but when it prints the EU date it gives me -1.-1.5 when i entered "02/13/2009"

Comment: Running a lot more smoothly, with a couple lines I will have to tweak so I can get the correct output. Thanks for your help

Comment: I have a question...when I run the program I am getting "/day/year.month.year"       so what is happening is it is still reading the / around the day string, and printing the year along with it. Do you know what could be causing this? It happens with any input I use.

Comment: If I run the code above, it works perfectly. Could you please post the changes you made? Based on the problem you described the +1s and -1's are probably messed up in the indexOf's

Comment: hm, I'm not quite sure how but thats exactly what it was...I had skipped over the "lastIndexOf" in the day string. It works perfect now. Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 3):

Why not split the input string using '/' as separator using the method `String.split`. It returns an array of strings. Just swap the first two elements of the array.

```
String usdate = "12/27/2015";
String[] arr = usdate.split("/");
String eudate = arr[1] + "/" + arr[0] + "/" + arr[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        String usString = kbd.nextLine();
        String[] stringArray = usString.split("(\\/|\\.)");
        String month = stringArray[0];
        String day = stringArray[1];
        String year = stringArray[2];
        System.out.println("m"+month+"d"+day+"y"+year);
```

This code shows how to use RegEx to split the sting into a string array which can then be re assembled into EU format without the DateFormat class.

Comment: In the qustion I said I could not use a dateformat or something along those lines, which would include SimpleDateFormat the reason is because I have not been taught that. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: I have updated the replay with code which should allow you to parse a date string that is separated by a "/" or a ".".

Comment: I see, this is helpful. Thanks